# Front-end session timeout causes error on checkout and basket pages

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, cart, session, checkoutsession

When user adds an item(or items) to the cart, it behaves normally. but if user tried to goto either checkot page or basket page after a while, it shows an error page as follows,

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): No such entity with cartId = 
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): No such entity with cartId = 
#0 E:\xampp\htdocs\magento_projects\jestic\vendor\magento\module-quote\Model\QuoteRepository.php(197): Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException::singleField('cartId', NULL)
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException): No such entity with cartId = 
#0C:xampp/htdocs/myProject/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteRepository.php(197): Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException::singleField('cartId', NULL)
#1C:xampp/htdocs/myProject/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteRepository.php(101): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository->loadQuote('load', 'cartId', NULL, Array)
#2C:xampp/htdocs/myProject/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteRepository.php(127): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository->get(NULL, Array)
#3C:xampp/htdocs/myProject/var/generation/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteRepository/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository->getActive(NULL, Array)
#4C:xampp/htdocs/myProject/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Item/Repository.php(69): Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository\Interceptor->getActive(NULL)
#5C:xampp/htdocs/myProject/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/Cart/ImageProvider.php(44): Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\Repository->getList(NULL)
#6C:xampp/htdocs/myProject/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php(278): Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\ImageProvider->getImages(NULL)
#7C:xampp/htdocs/myProject/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider->getConfig()
#8C:xampp/htdocs/myProject/var/generation/Magento/Checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getConfig', Array, Array)
#9C:xampp/htdocs/myProject/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Model/CompositeConfigProvider.php(32): Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider\Interceptor->getConfig()
#10C:xampp/htdocs/myProject/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Block/Cart/Shipping.php(54): Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider->getConfig()
```

and so on..

This happens when user tries to click on minicart icon before site gets fully loaded. (icon is clickable before site gets fully loaded and it linked to http://localhost/myProject/checkout/cart/)

I think usually there should be some standard web page with error message rather than showing errors like this.

What is wrong here? How can I fix this? please help...

Comment: Have you checked the answer below ?

Answer (score 1):

A similar issue is reported in Magento's GitHub issues list. This issue is resolved in Magento 2.2 as informed here in this comment.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6522#issuecomment-334663929

Also, you can verify the commit ID referenced in the above comment. The commit can be seen here - https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/e93c44e66d256836c18e6a5e7e9f24623f05e25b

If you update your Magento website to it's latest stable release, issue should not occur.

Comment: Can I redirect user to login page when session time out exceeded? it could be best if I show valid UI to user rather than big error

Comment: @Joey Does the above answer solve your previous problem ?

Comment: Not quite, thing is it may be some problem with my theme, but if so, I can't find it. Now I need to do something like redirecting user to login page when session expired. can you help me with that?

Comment: @Joey As a general rule, we should not mingle two questions in a single page. If you have more queries, please create a separate question for each of them.

Comment: actually it IS my actual question. I needed to know if I can fix this or stop showing this to user

Answer (score 1):

Is your development area is set to `Developer` ? It seems like `magento` bug as *Karthic* pointed out. However error reporting like this is common if you set your development to Developer. Try using `Production` mode and see if error shows then. If so, it's caused by buggy `magento` component. You may need to either update or manually try to fix the bug yourself.

Comment: Can I redirect user to login page when session time out exceeded? it could be best if I show valid UI to user rather than big error